# PHP cURL function related - what is the difference between browser visit, linux curl command and PHP cURL function?

Tags: php, http, post, curl, webserver

for the url "http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=sh600123"

i can get the response through any of the browser, the result as below,

> var hq_str_sh600123="兰花科创,13.53,13.63,13.45,13.61,13.43,13.45,13.46,1113110,15047856,3200,13.45,1500,13.44,11590,13.43,36900,13.42,68900,13.41,9800,13.46,6400,13.47,26496,13.48,14453,13.49,3400,13.50,2013-08-30,09:44:08,00";

also i can get the same response from the linux curl command

> curl http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=sh600123
>   var hq_str_sh600123="兰花科创,13.53,13.63,13.44,13.61,13.43,13.43,13.44,1144910,15475169,39090,13.43,37100,13.42,91000,13.41,235500,13.40,5800,13.39,800,13.44,41300,13.45,9800,13.46,6400,13.47,25496,13.48,2013-08-30,09:44:43,00";

but the big problem is i can't get the right response from the PHP cURL function

my trunk code is like this, have deleted the business logic

```
 $url = "http://hq.sinajs.cn/";//the url
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // the result could be got by the return value
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Expect:' )); // this line is added according to the advice from the internet
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

 $post_data = "list=".urldecode($code); // here the code can be "sh600485"
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

 $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

The $result is false, and i add verbose code like this :

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+'));
echo "Verbose information:\n<pre>", !rewind($verbose), htmlspecialchars(stream_get_contents($verbose)), "</pre>\n";
```

The output is

> Verbose information: 
>   * About to connect() to hq.sinajs.cn port 80 (#0)
>   *   Trying 202.108.37.102...
>   * connected
>   * Connected to hq.sinajs.cn (202.108.37.102) port 80 (#0)
>
> > POST / HTTP/1.1 Host: hq.sinajs.cn Accept: */* Content-Length: 13 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> - upload completely sent off: 13 out of 13 bytes
> - Empty reply from server
> - Connection #0 to host hq.sinajs.cn left intact
>
> Verbose information: 
>   * Connection #0 seems to be dead!
>   * Closing connection #0
>   * About to connect() to hq.sinajs.cn port 80 (#0)
>   *   Trying 202.108.37.102...
>   * connected
>   * Connected to hq.sinajs.cn (202.108.37.102) port 80 (#0)
>
> > POST / HTTP/1.1 Host: hq.sinajs.cn Accept: */* Content-Length: 13 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> - upload completely sent off: 13 out of 13 bytes
> - Empty reply from server
> - Connection #0 to host hq.sinajs.cn left intact

my question is why the difference from the result is so big?

1. what is the root cause the website server ? does it forbid the PHP cURL access?
2. how to solve the problem ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's possible the server checks for the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` header

Comment: i have already add the code like 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');
there is no use

Comment: echo "Info : " . curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

the result is "Info : 0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first two examples you are making HTTP `GET` requests. In your failing php/curl example, you are using HTTP `POST`.

I suspect you

Try changing the `CURLOPT_POST` option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
```

The following example works for me. Notice I've added the query parameter to the url and changed the HTTP method to `GET`.

```
<?php

$url = "http://<INSERT URL HERE>?list=sh600123";
//                              ^ use query params instead of post values...
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: but the same result :(

i also test using the code 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);

still not work

Comment: I added an example to my post that I think will do what you want.